# Typescript posting coming up as undefined when trying to connect mongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, typescript, express

I have the following two files and I'm trying to setup authentication but the incoming request comes up as undefined when I try to pass it through a function.

The code block

`console.log(req.params)`

Actually gives back the expected results, so if I were to send a request of...

http://localhost:5000/register/banana/john

...it would return

{ user: 'banana', password: 'john' }

but the following

`await mongoUser.register(user, password);`

I get

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'toBSON' of undefined`

If this happens to be a typescript specific problem, I apologize in advanced. I'm transitioning over from js so it's possible I'm not specifying a type somewhere.

**index.ts**

```js
import express, {Request, Response} from 'express';

const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const mongoUser = require("./mongoUser.ts");

/**
 * This is middleware
 */
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json())

app.post("/register/:user/:password", async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    try {
        console.log(req.params) //{ user: 'banana', password: 'john' }
        const {user, password} = await req.params;
        console.log(user); //banana
        console.log(password) //john
      
        await mongoUser.register(user, password); //error within

        res.json("Successfully registered!");
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
})

app.listen(5000, () => {
    console.log("server has started on port 5000");
});
```

**mongoUser.ts**

```js
export {};
const {MongoClient} = require('mongodb');
const credentials = require('./mongoAuth.json');
const uri = `${credentials.client}/${credentials.database}?retryWrites=true&w=majority`
const mongoClient = new MongoClient(uri);


module.exports = {

    validator: async () => {

    },

    login: async () => {

    },

    register: async (user: string, pass: string) => {
        await mongoClient.connect();

        await mongoClient.db(`${credentials.database}`).collection(`${credentials.collection[0]}`).updateOne(
            {
                $push: {
                    username: user,
                    password: pass
                }
            }
        )

        mongoClient.logout();
    },

    allUsers: async () => {

    },

}
```

**Error Message**

```js
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toBSON' of undefined
    at hasAtomicOperators (C:\Users\Home\WebstormProjects\sentimentalAnalysis\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:813:28)
    at new UpdateOneOperation (C:\Users\Home\WebstormProjects\sentimentalAnalysis\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\update_one.js:13:10)
    at Collection.updateOne (C:\Users\Home\WebstormProjects\sentimentalAnalysis\node_modules\mongodb\lib\collection.js:764:5)
    at C:\Users\Home\WebstormProjects\sentimentalAnalysis\src\server\mongoUser.ts:21:100
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (C:\Users\Home\WebstormProjects\sentimentalAnalysis\src\server\mongoUser.ts:5:58)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I'm sorry for wasting everyone's time but I figured it out. Basically, I wanted to add a new user and I was using code from another project where it adds an entry by updating a current one. So my current code was wrong because

1. I was using updateOne instead of insertOne
2. Even if I did want to use updateOne I needed to define a filter first which is why my ide wasn't even labeling $push as filter: and update: tags respectively

Below is the change I made

**mongoUser.ts**

```js
    register: async (user: string, pass: string) => {
        await mongoClient.connect();

        console.log("This is the user")
        console.log(user);


        await mongoClient.db(`${credentials.database}`).collection(`${credentials.collection[1]}`).insertOne(
            {
                username: user,
                password: pass
            }
        )

        mongoClient.logout();
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Hm, the first thing I notice is that in the first snippet in the `await mongoUser.register(username, password); //error within` line you use `username` as variable, whereas above you only defined `user` and `password`..

Might this be the problem?

Comment: I did make sure that the parameters being passed were correct but I didn't completely change it in the stackoverflow post, I'll change it now I still have the same problem

Comment: I figured it out, sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 0):

Try forcing unified topology when creating instance of new Mongo client, like so `const mongoClient = new MongoClient(uri, { useUnifiedTopology: true });` here is the link to more details - https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-2091

Comment: I figured it out, sorry for wasting your time.